# D3: What projection am I using? / How to simplify with a null projection?

Tags: d3.js, map-projections, simplification

I am attempting to simplify a d3 map on zoom, and I am using [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6242308) as a starting point. However, when I replace the json file in the example with my own (http://weather-bell.com/res/nws_regions.topojson), I get a tiny upside-down little map.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8ejmH
code:

```
var width = 900,
    height = 500;

var chesapeake = [-75.959, 38.250];

var scale,
translate,
visibleArea, // minimum area threshold for points inside viewport
invisibleArea; // minimum area threshold for points outside viewport

var simplify = d3.geo.transform({
    point: function (x, y, z) {
        if (z < visibleArea) return;
        x = x * scale + translate[0];
        y = y * scale + translate[1];
        if (x >= 0 && x <= width && y >= 0 && y <= height || z >= invisibleArea) this.stream.point(x, y);
    }
});

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .size([width, height])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

// This projection is baked into the TopoJSON file,
// but is used here to compute the desired zoom translate.
var projection = d3.geo.mercator().translate([0, 0])



var canvas = d3.select("#map").append("canvas")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(simplify)
    .context(context);

d3.json("http://weather-bell.com/res/nws_regions.topojson", function (error, json) {
    canvas.datum(topojson.mesh(topojson.presimplify(json)))
        .call(zoomTo(chesapeake, 0.05).event)
        .transition()
        .duration(5000)
        .each(jump);
});

function zoomTo(location, scale) {
    var point = projection(location);
    return zoom.translate([width / 2 - point[0] * scale, height / 2 - point[1] * scale])
        .scale(scale);
}

function zoomed(d) {
    translate = zoom.translate();
    scale = zoom.scale();
    visibleArea = 1 / scale / scale;
    invisibleArea = 200 * visibleArea;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    context.beginPath();
    path(d);
    context.stroke();
}

function jump() {
    var t = d3.select(this);
    (function repeat() {
        t = t.transition()
            .call(zoomTo(chesapeake, 100).event)
            .transition()
            .call(zoomTo(chesapeake, 0.05).event)
            .each("end", repeat);
    })();
}
```

My guess is that the topojson file I am using already has the projection built in, so I should be using a null projection in d3. 
The map renders properly if I do not use a projection at all: (http://jsfiddle.net/KQfrK/1/) - but then I cannot simplify on zoom.

I feel like I am missing something basic... perhaps I just need to somehow rotate and zoom into the map in my first fiddle.

Either way, I'd appreciate some help. Been struggling with this one.

**Edit:** I used QGIS to save the geojson file with a "EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator" projection.
However, when I convert this to topojson with the topojson command-line utility and then display it with D3 using the same code as above I get a blank screen.

Should I specify the projection within the topojson command-line utility? I tried to do that but I got an error message:

```
topojson --projection EPSG:3857 E:\gitstore\public\res\nws.geojson -o E:\gitstore\public\res\nws.topojson --id-property NAME


[SyntaxError: Unexpected token :]
```

Answer (score 0):

The TopoJSON file doesn't have a projection built-in, you're simply using the default projection when you don't specify one (which is albersUsa, see [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#wiki-path_projection)). You can retrieve this projection by calling `d3.geo.projection()` without an argument. Then you can modify this projection in the usual way for zoom etc.

Comment: If I replace d3.geo.mercator() with d3.geo.projection() I get an error message: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'invert' of undefined." If I replace it with d3.geo.albersUsa() then I get another upside down little map that flies in a different direction.

Comment: You need to adjust your hardcoded coordinates etc to be valid for that projection as well.

Comment: please see my upadate - I am trying to translate the map to a mercator projection and hardcode it into the topojson file.

Comment: Ok, that's a different thing. You need to give one of the [D3 projections](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo-projection) to topojson though.

Comment: @ Mike, I've bumped your second fiddle [to here](http://jsfiddle.net/j27BT/) including altered projection and path lines which might clarify  few things.  To me it looks as though your json is in Mercator.

Answer (score 0):

I set up this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rHmev/1/) using the Mercator projection and I took a different approach to zooming in and out based on [this block](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590), which to me was a simpler approach. I have a feeling that there was an issue in the zoomTo function in the translate bit, but I could exactly what it was. So I replaced with the code below and included a recursive call:

```
function clicked(k) {

    if (typeof k === 'undefined') k = 8;

    g.transition()
        .duration(5000)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" + -projection(chesapeake)[0] + "," + -projection(chesapeake)[1] + ")")
        .each("end", function () {
        (k === 8) ? k = 1 : k = 8;
        clicked(k);
    });
```